# Delete $2^{k-1}$ numbers from $(0, 2^n+1)$ interval; the maximum distance between deleted numbers at step $k$ must be $2^{n-k}$

Tags: algorithms, divide-and-conquer

## The problem

I have two integers, $n$ and $p$:

$n \ge 1$

$1 \le p \le 2^n + 1$

Consider the sequence of numbers: $0, 1, 2, ..., 2^n, 2^n + 1$.

$0$, $p$, and $2^n + 1$ in the sequence are marked as deleted.

I need an algorithm that can mark all the elements of the sequence as deleted , ***in k steps*** (k from 1 to n), with the following restrictions:

1. At a certain step $k$ I must mark as deleted $2^{k-1}$ numbers.
2. At the end of the step $k$, the distance between 2 consecutive "marked as deleted" numbers must not exceed $2^{n - k}$.
3. I can't mark a number as deleted, if the number was already marked so in a previous step.

## What I've come up with

At a certain step $k$, I should split the sequence into $2^{k-1}$ sequences and mark as deleted every number in the middle of every obtained sequence. However, the problem with this is that there already is a marked as deleted number $p$, which interferes with my proposed process, because I still nedd to fulfill the requirement of marking $2^{k-1}$ numbers as deleted at the step $k$.

Comment: What context did you run across this problem in?  What have you tried?  1. You marked this as divide-and-conquer.  Have you tried applying divide-and-conquer?  At the start of step $k$, can you find two or more problem instances that look similar to the original?  2. Have you tried working through this, step-by-step?  Start with step 1: which numbers would it be legal to mark?  Now how about step 2: which numbers would it be legal to mark?  Try step 3.  And then can you generalize?  We want to help you understand concepts, not solve your exercise problem for you.